# Disable past dates except for single date in mat-datepicker Angular

Tags: angular, mat-datepicker

I want disable past dates except 13-04-2023 in mat-datepicker. Currently i create datepicker with custom filter function to disable past dates except for 13-04-2023 but this dont working:(

```
  myFilter = (date: Date | null): boolean => {
    const today = new Date()
    if(!date) { return false }

    return date >= today && !this.isSameDate(date)
  };

  isSameDate(date1: Date) {
    return date1.toDateString() === this.excludedDate.toDateString()
  }

  this.excludedDate = new Date(2023, 3, 13)


  <input matInput formControlName="effectiveDate" [matDatepicker]="pickerFrom" [matDatepickerFilter]="myFilter"/>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="pickerFrom"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #pickerFrom ></mat-datepicker>
```

I cant choose past date, so its nice but i also can't pick 13-04-2023

[image]

Whats is the fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `matDatepickerFilter` predicate should return `true` for dates that are enabled.

Your predicate says "date have to be greater or equal than today AND not equal `excludedDate`". Since your `excludedDate` is in the past, those two parts are mutually exclusive.

I assume you were aiming for something like:

```
return date >= today || this.isSameDate(date)
```